# With the help of the segmented control navigating web pages

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to navigate web pages with the help of segmented controls?

I do have four web pages I need to navigate, one after the another, can anybody help me out?

Does anybody have the example with this related one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Segmented Controls or Page Control?

Comment: Do you want to navigate when user selects option in segmented control?

Comment: yeap pratikshabhishikar....... that perfect....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit the view with a `UIWebView` object and a `UISegmentedControl` object. Wire an outlet to `webView` in the controller and connect the segmented control's `valueChanged` event in IB to a IBAction `-changeWebSource:(UISegmentedControl*)` and define its implementation as follows –

```
- (IBAction)changeWebSource:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    NSURL *sourceURL;

    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
            sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
            break;

        case 1:
            sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
            break;

        case 2:
            sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"];
            break;

        case 3:
            sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.microsoft.com"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:sourceURL]];
}
```

Change the urls as you wish. But I am not sure how this will ensure they visit the pages one after the other as you wanted. Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: what if i do have N urls pages and i need to access with there related ID

Comment: Use an array and let segmentIndex map to the arrayIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Then see the class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```